# How to find and click automatically based on the specific url in html in the bash script

Tags: bash, loops, command

I want to when the bash script executes the open url in Firefox and then continues by searching for the specific url and clicking it automatically. how to work?

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line; do
firefox --private-window "$line" & 2>/dev/null
sleep 40
killall firefox
done < blash
```

especially in the bash script loop. thankyou

> illustration: when firefox opens the url at http:// aaaaa.com in the
>   html website there is a http:// bbbbb.com url and the bash script
>   automatically searches and clicks it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not work this way. You want to:

a) Use cURL and request the initial URL, parse the output so you can find the second URL, send a POST/GET request to it.

b) Use something like Selenium to automate this process.

Comment: ok thanks for information